# The opposite of userIsCheckable enum, in Python & QT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

We have Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable flag, I need the opposite of it
that will probably be something like Qt.ItemIsUser**Un**Checkable but this obviously does not exist
Had it been we have it as a function like setItemIsUserCheckable, what i need will be setItemIsUserCheckable(False)

I want to setFlag() on a QTreeWidgetItem, we are looking at allowing just privileged users to be able to check or uncheck the QTreeWidgetItem, we could have gone ahead to just disable the item, but we really dont want the Items faded like it does when disabled so setDisabled() is not an option

Answer (score 2):

These flags are in fact bit flags. I think you can disable a specific flag just like this (in c++ syntax):

```
Qt::ItemFlags flags = myTreeWidgetItem->flags();
flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
myTreeWidgetItem->setFlags(flags);
```

Comment: I converted this to python and it worked like magic. Mind explaining whats going on there. With my years of coding python, i haven't come across the above.

Comment: These are simple logical operations. You have a bit flag Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable. In memory it looks something like this: `01000000`. Then you invert it (`~` operator): `10111111`. And then you do logical conjunction with your initial set of flags. After that the second bit (in this example) will be 'turned off'.

Answer (score 0):

Final code that worked below, might help someone else

```
flags = myTreeWidgetItem.flags()
flags &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
item.setFlags(flags)
```